# Director field fluctuations in a liquid crystal in a magnetic field

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

If we consider the Frank elastic free energy in the equal constants limit (for more details, see [here](http://www2.mpip-mainz.mpg.de/~andrienk/teaching/IMPRS/liquid_crystals.pdf) Chapter 4.1.) with an external magnetic field, we have

$$
F = \frac{1}{2}\int \text{d}^3 r\left ( K|\nabla \cdot n|^2 + K|\nabla\times n|^2 -\Delta\chi |n\cdot H|^2  \right),
$$
where $K$ is the elastic constant, $n$ is the unit director field ($n\cdot n =1$), $\Delta \chi$ is the magnetic susceptibility anisotropy and $H$ denotes the magnetic field.

Suppose we take the ground state director field in de z-direction: $n_0 = (0,0,1)$. A fluctuation on his field will be of the form $\delta n \approx (\delta n_x, \delta n_y,0)$ for small $\delta n_x(r)$ and $\delta n_y(r)$. In the case of zero magnetic field, I understand the system. We introduce the Fourier transform
$$
\delta n_{\alpha}(r) = \frac{1}{V}\sum_q \delta\tilde{n}_{\alpha}(q)e^{iqr}
$$
and its inverse
$$
\delta \tilde{n}(q)=\int \text{d} r \delta n_{\alpha}(r)e^{-iqr},
$$
to obtain

$$
F \approx \frac{K}{2V}\sum_q \left( \delta \tilde{n}^2_x(q) + \delta \tilde{n}^2_y(q)  \right)q^2.
$$
Now one can impose equipartition of free energy: every mode in the Fourier decomposition carries $k_B T/2$ of energy. This yields the correlators
$$
\langle \delta \tilde{n}_{\alpha}^2(q) \rangle = \frac{k_B T V}{Kq^2} \Rightarrow \langle \delta n_{\alpha}(0)\delta n_{\alpha}(r) \rangle = \frac{k_B T}{4\pi K |r|}.
$$
However, I do not understand how this works in the case of a magnetic field. Suppose we take the initial magnetic field also in the z-direction. The free energy then becomes
$$
F \approx \frac{K}{2}\sum_q \left( \delta \tilde{n}^2_x(q) + \delta \tilde{n}^2_y(q)  \right)q^2 - \frac{1}{2}\Delta \chi V H_z^2.
$$

I do not understand how I can invoke the equipartition theorem to find the correlation functions in this new situation. Can anyone help?

EDIT: the form of the fluctuations is derived as follows. Say we have $\delta n = (\delta n_x, \delta n_y, \delta n_z)$, then we must have $|n+\delta n|^2 = 1$, yielding a conditions $1+\delta n_z = \sqrt{1-\delta n_x^2 - \delta n_y^2} \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}(\delta n_x^2+\delta n_y^2) \approx 1$ for small $\delta n_x$ and $\delta n_y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the fact that one should not neglect the terms quadratic in $\delta n_x$ and $\delta n_y$. For a field in the z-direction one obtains
$$
\int d^3 r  |n \cdot H|^2 = \int d^3 r (1-\delta n_x^2 H_z - \delta n_y^2 H_z),
$$
where the first term is an irrelevant shift. Performing the Fourier transform, one finds
$$
F \approx \frac{1}{2V}\sum_q \left( \delta \tilde{n}^2_x(q)(Kq^2 - \Delta \chi H_z) + \delta \tilde{n}^2_y(q)(Kq^2 - \Delta \chi H_z)  \right),
$$
which leads upon contour integration to
$$
\langle \delta n_{\alpha}(0)\delta n_{\alpha}(r) \rangle = \frac{k_B T}{4\pi K |r|}e^{-r/\xi},
$$
with $\xi$ a correlation length in terms of $\Delta\chi, H$ and $K$. The interpretation is that fluctuations in the x,y-direction are exponentially surpressed when a magnetic field along the z-direction is applied.